# Exceed parent element that has overflow set to scroll

Tags: css

This is the code:

```
<div class="c1">
  <div class="c2">
    <div class="c3">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<style>
  .c1{
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: visible;
    margin: 50px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: red;
  }
  .c2{
    width: 200px;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: yellow; 
  }
  .c3{
    margin-left: -50%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is have scroll functionality for the y-axis while having the green div exceed the other to the left, like it would if overflow-y is unset for the red div. Is this possible at all? Here is the code to test: https://liveweave.com/RCeADH

Comment: which one is the ' green '  div ? :) you have 2 red and 1 yellow :)

Comment: .c3 has a background-color of green in the link, but it has a background-color of red in the "This is the code:" display.

Comment: .c3 is supposed to be green, sorry